# Passing a Vector as parameter to another class constructor C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, parameters, constructor

I have been trying to pass a vector to another class constructor by using the following line: (the following line of code is in the Lexer.cpp class)

```
 Parser p(toks);
```

where, toks is a vector of type Token ( `vector<Token> toks;` ) , with Token being a struct within the Lexer.h class.

The constructor to which I would like to pass this vector is the following:

```
Parser::Parser(vector<Lexer::Token> toks){
    //do something
}
```

However, using `Parser p(toks);` to pass the vector is giving me an 'Instantiating an unknown structure without a reference' error. In what way should I pass this vector to the other class?

Comment: Have you included "Lexer.h" header (where `Token` should be *defined*) properly?

Comment: @BiagioFesta yes I have!

Answer (score 1):

add a & symbo

```
Parser::Parser(vector<Lexer::Token> &toks){
//do something
}
```

Comment: unrelated to the error. and `const` is also missing, should be a comment, not an answer (and you cannot currently comment :-/ ).